# CSS Grid for production?

Tags: css, css-grid

My designer is adamant about implementing CSS Grid for our next product.  My argument is I'll still have to write fallbacks for all of the css-grid properties as most of our clients use IE10/11.

Are there any benefits to using CSS Grid if I still have to write all of the fallbacks?  If so, what?

Comment: This is probably going to get closed as primarily opinion based because that's what it comes down to — choosing the right tradeoff. That being said, why does your designer have a say in what technologies you use to implement the design?

Comment: If most of your clients use IE10/11, then you should build products optimized for IE10/11. This means stay away from CSS Grid, which is designed for newer browsers.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that was the question I was looking for.  It's easier to have a stack overflow answer with multiple people saying the same thing than it just sounding like I'm being lazy.

Comment: Designer used mock ups in Zeplin utilizing the CSS grid.  It sounds like he doesn't want to redo the designs, and I don't want to implement fall back code that could be used as the main code.  I can show this thread to my boss and ask him to have the designer redo the designs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this depends on what you're planning on doing. You won't be able to do some of the fancier things that CSS Grid can do on modern browsers such as using the `repeat` function on `grid-template-columns` ([repeat() - MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat)). If you end up doing that you'll need to completely recreate your layout as a fallback for the IE browsers. If you're able to limit yourself to only use the properties that are supported by IE with -ms- prefixes then you may not need a fallback at all.

I found the following resources really useful when determining whether to use CSS Grid on a recent project that is supporting IE10/11:

- [Should I try to use the IE implementation of CSS Grid Layout?](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/11/26/should-i-try-to-use-the-ie-implementation-of-css-grid-layout/)
- [Grid by Example](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/)

I ran into a situation recently where CSS Grid seemed to be the best way to approach building a strange grid layout that I was tasked to create.

I was able to use -ms- prefixes to get my layout working in IE10 so it worked out for me (I also ran into an issue with grid in Safari which is present in the examples below, but I was able to solve that)

Here it is on Codepen: https://codepen.io/katrina-isabelle/pen/MxzQNR

```css
.grid-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 60%;
}

.grid {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  -ms-grid-columns: 29% 21% 21% 29%;
  grid-template-columns: 29% 21% 21% 29%;
  -ms-grid-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 100%;
  color: #ccc;
  background: #ccc;
}
.grid-item--1 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: span 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 2;
}
.grid-item--2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: span 3;
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 3;
}
.grid-item--3 {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: span 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 2;
}
.grid-item--4 {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: span 3;
  -ms-grid-column: 4;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 3;
}
.grid-item--5 {
  grid-row: span 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 2;
}
.grid-item--6 {
  grid-row: span 3;
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 3;
}
.grid-item--7 {
  grid-row: span 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 2;
}
.grid-item--8 {
  grid-row: span 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 4;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 2;
}
.grid-item--9 {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--1">
      Grid item
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--2">
      Grid item
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--3">
      Grid item
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--4">
      Grid item
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--5">
      Grid item
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--6">
      Grid item
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--7">
      Grid item
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--8">
      Grid item
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--9">
      Grid item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this question.  I just spent half a day doing Wes Bos' course on CSS Grid and realized that most of the cool neat features that would make CSS Grid development clean and fast wouldn't work in IE.  I think I have enough fire power to have the designer redo the designs now.

Answer (score 1):

The original implementation of Grid happened in IE 10, but it worked a little differently and didn't include all of the features it does today. So depending on what you're actually doing, you may be able to get away with adding the `ms` prefixes to your CSS rules.

Or you could look into progressive enhancement. I.e. falling back to something like floats if grid isn't available. MDN has a good article on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/CSS_Grid_and_Progressive_Enhancement).

Or just not use grid at all if most or a large enough number of your users are coming from older browsers that don't fully support it.

As far as are there benefits if you need to write fallbacks, probably not if you aren't doing anything with grid that can't be done as well or almost as well with floats.

Comment: I will definitely have to be writing fallbacks so it seems like a lot of overhead if I already have to write something for when it doesn't work.